# How to improve UI development skills (for a Java developer)?

Tags: user-interface

I have worked on backend development with mostly Java. For past 6 months I have been working on UI a lot and I want to improve my skills. I am aware of HTML, CSS and JavaScript (also jQuery and YUI) but I have never been able to master them so that I can develop efficient and maintainable solutions much quicker than how I do now. Can other UI developers give me any tips/resources? I also wanted to learn about patterns and best practices for UI development.

Comment: @stakx - No, not good for programmers. I wish more people would read the programmers [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) before pointing off-topic questions to it.

Comment: @stakx - Not every question has a place on a Stack Exchange site. When suggesting a site (say [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) in this case), I would still urge the OP to read the FAQ and decide whether the question will find a home there.

Comment: @stakx - That's my point. I have not read the UX FAQ, so can't tell. If their FAQ points out that it is off-topic, so be it.

Comment: @Oded, I've removed my previous comments. That discussion wasn't going anywhere. I'll just restate part of my original post: "@bluetech: Interesting question, but perhaps not a good fit for Stack Overflow."